# equation of a line into the complex form

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So if i am given an equation of a line in complex form for example $Re|(1+i)z| = 0$, I could turn this into its real counter part on the x-y plane and graph it. Is there a way to go in the other direction? So say i have the equation of a line in $y = mx + b$ form, can i turn it into some complex expressiom of the form Re (complex expression here)?

For some reason my question was not getting approved so consider this chnchunk just extra text

Comment: $|(1+i)z|$ is already real

Comment: do you mean $\Re((1+i)z)=0$?

Comment: Well i just plucked that out as an exampl, i am more interested in going from the y = mx+b form into an expression involving a complex

Answer (score 2):

All lines in $\mathbb C$ can be written as

$$\beta z + \bar\beta \ \bar z + \gamma = 0$$

where $\beta \in \mathbb C$, $\gamma \in \mathbb R$.

Now write $z = x + iy$ and simplify the expression; impose that it should be equal to $y = mx + b$ and you'll find $\beta$

Comment: Can, by your definition, any line  in $\mathbb C^2$ be written as $ax+by+c=0$ for $a,b,c\in \mathbb C$?

Comment: @GregoryGrant why $\mathbb C^2$?

Comment: Oh I see, you mean a one dimensional line in $\Bbb C$.  I was thinking the solutions of a linear equation in $\Bbb C^2$.

Comment: To me the only line in $\Bbb C$ is $\Bbb C$ itself.  But that's thinking as an algebraist, not a geometer.

Comment: Im not sure i fully follow @Ant. I mean isn't that expression meaning that i already know the z-form?

Answer (score 0):

Given $y = mx + b$, find the perpendicular to it from the origin. That line is given by $y = -\frac{1}{m}x$. The complex number $1 + \frac{1}{m}i$ will rotate and scale the first line so that it's vertical. To find the real part, compute the real part of $(1+\frac{1}{m}i)bi$, which is $\frac{-b}{m}$. So that gives $\Re((1+\frac{1}{m}i)z) = \frac{-b}{m}$

Comment: How did yiu get $1+\frac {1}{m}i $ i got lost from there